# How can I configure Doxygen to include typedefs of classes in the "Class Index"?

Tags: c++, doxygen

How can I configure Doxygen to include typedefs of classes in the "Class Index" web page?   For example, if the code has

```
typedef std::map<std::string /* month name */, std::string /* yield */> MonthlyYieldMap;
```

somewhere, then `MonthlyYieldMap` acts like a class, so it seems reasonable to include it in the Class Index just like the other names that refer to classes.

If I'm inspecting someone else's code and see the name of something that acts like a class but that is unfamiliar to me, then I pull up the Class Index to look for details of the class, but if the name is a typedef then it is not shown.

I can still find information about the mysterious name through the Doxygen search bar on the Class Index web page, but it would be more convenient if it were mentioned in the Class Index.

I've looked through the configuration file and found two that mention typedefs (INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS and TYPEDEF_HIDE_STRUCT) but they don't address my problem.

ADDED 2018-07-05:

If I can edit the code, then I can change the typedef to a class inheriting the other class:

```
class MonthlyYieldMap : public std::map<std::string, std::string> { }
```

and then it is included in the Class Index.  I don't know if there is a performance or executable size penalty for doing this.  And this doesn't help if I cannot edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

A `typedef` is not a `class` and this is not foreseen.
A not so nice solution as it does not mention that the `MonthlyYieldMap` is a `typedef` but says that it is a function  (I don't how acceptable this is in your case) is:

```
/**
  * @class MonthlyYieldMap
  */
/**
  * some documentation
  * \relates MonthlyYieldMap
  */
typedef std::map<std::string /* month name */, std::string /* yield */> MonthlyYieldMap;
```